# A property in a struct not being updated after being computed in willSet observer

Tags: swift, computed-properties, didset, property-observer

Sorry in advance if my question comes across being stupid, I'm currently learning property observers and I've been given an example from a great swift tutorial online to determine if the code is valid, I correctly assumed it was and decided to implement it in Swift playgrounds. I don't understand why the **isMillionaire** property remains false despite the if statement evaluating to true.

```
struct BankAccount{
var name: String
var isMillionaire = false
var balance: Int {
    didSet {
        if balance > 1_000_000 {
            isMillionaire = true
        } else {
            isMillionaire = false
        }
    }
  }
}

var bankUser1 = BankAccount(name: "John Appleseed", balance: 2_000_000)
print(bankUser1.isMillionaire) //Returns false
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and remove the image and paste actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Property observers are not called on initialisation, only when the value is set after that, that's why `didSet` is not being executed.

In this specific case, since `isMillionaire` is completely derived from `balance` and shouldn't be able to be updated directly, I would recommend using a computed property, so it would look like this:

```
var isMillionaire: Bool {
  return balance > 1_000_000
}
```